# Connectivity problems when setting up a ReplicaSet via the MongoDB Node.js client

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mesos, marathon

I'm trying to build an scalable ReplicaSet via Apache Mesos and Marathon. Therefore, I created a Docker file which contains MongoDB 3.0.7 and a Node.js application which registers itself to the `eventSubscriptions` API of marathon, meaning that it reacts on events from Marathon.

Those are filtered by application, for example triggering a ReplicaSet init when the first node is up, and adding members to the ReplicaSet when the next nodes come up too.

Initialization works flawlessly, but when I try to add the next nodes to the ReplicaSet, MongoDB reports an error:

```
2015-10-22T08:52:58.639+0000 I REPL     [conn18] replSetReconfig admin command received from client
2015-10-22T08:52:58.641+0000 W NETWORK  [conn18] Failed to connect to 192.168.200.167:31069, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2015-10-22T08:52:58.641+0000 I REPL     [conn18] replSetReconfig config object with 2 members parses ok
2015-10-22T08:52:58.641+0000 W NETWORK  [ReplExecNetThread-0] Failed to connect to 192.168.200.167:31069, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2015-10-22T08:52:58.691+0000 W REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] Failed to complete heartbeat request to 192.168.200.167:31069; Location18915 Failed attempt to connect to 192.168.200.167:31069; couldn't connect to server 192.168.200.167:31069 (192.168.200.167), connection attempt failed
2015-10-22T08:52:58.691+0000 E REPL     [conn18] replSetReconfig failed; NodeNotFound Quorum check failed because not enough voting nodes responded; required 2 but only the following 1 voting nodes responded: 192.168.200.168:31970; the following nodes did not respond affirmatively: 192.168.200.167:31069 failed with Failed attempt to connect to 192.168.200.167:31069; couldn't connect to server 192.168.200.167:31069 (192.168.200.167), connection attempt failed
```

I tried to verify if the connectivity works, and I can successfully connect to the given connection info:

```
$mongo --host 192.168.200.167 --port 31069
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.7
connecting to: 192.168.200.167:31069/test
Server has startup warnings:
2015-10-22T08:52:59.212+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
>
```

So, for me the connectivity seems to be there. Next thing I checked if the new ReplicaSet configuration I create for reconfiguring the ReplicaSet works:

```
{
    "_id": "rs0",
    "version": 2,
    "members": [
        {
            "_id": 0,
            "host": "192.168.200.168:31970",
            "arbiterOnly": false,
            "buildIndexes": true,
            "hidden": false,
            "priority": 1,
            "tags": {},
            "slaveDelay": 0,
            "votes": 1
        },
        {
            "_id": 1,
            "host": "192.168.200.167:31069"
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "chainingAllowed": true,
        "heartbeatTimeoutSecs": 30,
        "getLastErrorModes": {},
        "getLastErrorDefaults": {
            "w": 1,
            "wtimeout": 0
        }
    }
}
```

This config is executed by issueing

```
db.admin().command({replSetReconfig: myConfig}, function(error, newConfigResult) { ... });
```

This configuration triggers the above error in the MongoDB logs, and the following one in the Node.js application log:

```
{
    "name": "MongoError",
    "message": "Quorum check failed because not enough voting nodes responded; required 2 but only the following 1 voting nodes responded: 192.168.200.168:31970; the following nodes did not respond affirmatively: 192.168.200.167:31069 failed with Failed attempt to connect to 192.168.200.167:31069; couldn't connect to server 192.168.200.167:31069 (192.168.200.167), connection attempt failed",
    "ok": 0,
    "errmsg": "Quorum check failed because not enough voting nodes responded; required 2 but only the following 1 voting nodes responded: 192.168.200.168:31970; the following nodes did not respond affirmatively: 192.168.200.167:31069 failed with Failed attempt to connect to 192.168.200.167:31069; couldn't connect to server 192.168.200.167:31069 (192.168.200.167), connection attempt failed",
    "code": 74
}
```

Now, the event stranger thing is if I use the configuration and run it directly on the primary's MongoDB shell via

```
db.runCommand({replSetReconfig: myConfigFromAbove});
```

it also works... Does someone have an idea what could be the actual problem? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Why the closing vote, with no suggestion? I think this perfectly fits SO...